# Django Rest API that takes in SQL query and return the result of the executed query from Database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to design a dynamic API with Django Rest and the requirement is slightly unique.

The API is meant to take in an SQL query and execute that query and return the result of that query. So basically it can be a GET request that returns some data, or a POST request that inserts some data.

I currently have no idea how this can be achieved so any advice/example would be greatly appreciated. And also, will it be simpler to go with plain Django, or with Django Rest Framework?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that sounds a bit dangerous, to be honest, hope you know what you are doing ;) If you are going to allow people to write their own queries to your database you'll have to think about the security implications of that.

But I suggest that you read this documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/) about performing raw SQL queries.

Comment: you're right about the risk that I need to be careful with :) I'm just exploring the possibilities of implementing this feature. It will come later, of course, the authentication and authorization aspect. Thanks for the suggestion, let me study it.